# Least squares optimization

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to solve the problem below:

> Given the input data (25 columns), find the optimal coefficients and powers to return the least squared sum of errors based on the target value. Coefficients must be bound between `[0, inf)` and powers are bound between `[0,3]`, both inclusive.

I am having trouble figuring out the best way to do this in Python. I currently have the data in a `csv` that I imported as a `Dataframe`. I was thinking `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear` might work, but I am unsure how this would look because of the large number of input variables.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, .csv to Dataframe is the right reflex.

Sickit learn has a fast linear regression: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html